# dynamic display of JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am new to swing .I am using JTree to construct a tree in swing.
Is there any method to construct tree when we click on button in the same window?

Means something like when i select some button it will show me tree.

Comment: Do you mean adding things to an existing tree or showing different trees?

Comment: showing diffrent tree. thanks:)

Comment: Of course there is - actually all JTrees are created in the same manner. You create a TreeModel, and use `new JTree(model)`, and put this JTree at the right place in your window. Where is your problem, actually? (Add this to your question, please.)

Answer (score 1):

The general code for adding components to a visible GUI is:

```
panel.add( someComponent );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```